# Unable to import a sql or xml file

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, wordpress

I have recently moved some of my sites from shared hosting to VPS. 
When I am importing SQL files through phpmyadmin or xml files through Wordpress import tool, I am getting error saying "The connection was reset". Can anyone help me with this.
I have already made changes to php.ini file. 
Location of file : /etc/php5/fpm/php.ini 
I have already changed - 
max_execution_time = 8000 
max_input_time = 8000 
post_max_size = 8G 
upload_max_filesize = 2G
Anything other than this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try upping max_packet_size to 2G.... that may fix it.

also, dont import thru gui,,,, ssh in and import in screen, from the cli....

> mysql -u user -ppassword dbname < dbname.sql

edit; max_packet_size is a mysql directive, not php.  by doing via mysql shell, you are bypassing php and its limits all together.